# How do I use a random number I generated in a separate sum

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I'm a complete beginner and trying to create a Times Table game app that asks the user to input a number, generates a multiplication sum, and then checks if it's the write answer to deliver a congratulations message and then adds the score.

I've managed to generate the random number, but when I input the correct answer I get the Incorrect message which makes me think that the random number is not pulling through to the second button. Any help much appreciated!

Button 1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userInput = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    if (userInput >= 1 && userInput <= 10)
    {
        Random rNum = new Random();   //uses built in function Random()
        int rrNum = rNum.Next(1, 12);  // creates a number between 1 and 12
        label5.Text = (Convert.ToString(rrNum) + " x " + userInput);
    }
}
```

Button 2

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    Random rNum = new Random();
    int rrNum = rNum.Next(1, 12);
    if (userAnswer == userInput * rrNum)
    {
        label8.Text = "Congratulations!";
        pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        label8.Text = ("Incorrect, try again!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't declare the random instance inside that routine (local scope), declare it outside at class level and re-use it.

Comment: @madreflection: MS has changed it in .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/2192 It's also mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Random__ctor).

Comment: @zaggler Thanks, though as a total beginner I'm still a bit confused by your examples. Should I add: 

Random rNum = new Random();
        int rrNum = rNum.Next(1, 12);

to outside the button, to the overall?

Comment: @NM120 If you need a number between 1 and 12 (inclusive), then you should use `rNum.Next(1, 13)`. [The upper bound is exclusive.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)